# iOS Core Data - Double (NSNumber) value changes the second time I access it

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a Core Data that has a Double number, and the Swift class has it as NSNumber. When I open a ViewController, then access the value, it's fine. If I access it again, the value changes. For example, one object has its NSNumber change from 56.5 to 7770.5, every time. Does this have anything to do with choosing Double and NSNumber instead of Decimal and NSDecimalNumber?

I might perform a migration if that's true, but I can't lose the previous value that was saved.

Comment: number type will affect precision but not a complete change of value. You probably have a bug somewhere.

Comment: Did you try running your debugger to monitor the value you are saving from beginning to end?

Comment: Can you show some code? Also, do you have ARC turned on? This sounds like an `NSNumber` that's getting released  and perhaps  another object is being put in its place.

Comment: @AndyIbanez It was actually an array of this object. I clicked watch variable and it stopped at 'symbol stub for: swift_bridgeObjectRelease'

Comment: @user1118321 It stopped at 'symbol stub for: swift_bridgeObjectRelease', which implies you're right. The thing is, the other values in the object (which is an array element) stay the same.